# Magento 1.7 Help with pulling values from array

Tags: magento-1.7, sku, array

I am trying to get some values from an array. my code below i need to get a comma separated values the values from the sku KEY, i am just not sure how to do it.

Example output I need: sku,sku,sku

```
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
$order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);

$orderItems = array();
foreach($order->getItemsCollection() as $item)
{
    //$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
    $row=array();
    $row['sku'] = $item->getProduct()->getData('model');
    $orderItems[]=$row;
}
echo print_r($orderItems);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not 100% what you are trying to do here, so you may need to give an example. If your intent is to simply collect all of the skus, I would first ver_dump($item->getData()) because your item may already have the sku, in which case your code would look something like:

```
foreach($order->getItemsCollection() as $item)
{
$orderItems['sku'][] = $item->getSku();
}
```

If you don't have the sku on your item an need to load the product, you can slightly alter the code to:

```
foreach($order->getItemsCollection() as $item)
{
$orderItems['sku'][] = $item->getProduct()->getSku();
}
```

If model and sku are different and you want an array with sku keys and model values, consider this code:

```
foreach($order->getItemsCollection() as $item)
{
$product = $item->getProduct();
$orderItems[$product->getSku()] = $product->getModel();
}
```

Again, you may want to just give a clearer example of what you're looking for if I didn't cover it.

EDIT:

Apologies. The way you originally set up your question led me to use a 2D array. This should cover your issue:

```
 foreach($order->getItemsCollection() as $item) { 
    $orderItems[] = $item->getProduct()->getSku(); 
 } 
 $comma_separated = implode(",", $orderItems); 
 echo $comma_separated;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response here the second one produced this output: Array ( [sku] => Array ( [0] => skua[1] => skub ) )  when I ran it which is good but i need it to look like this: skua,skub,skuc,

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you mean? When you say that you need it to be "Sku,sku,sku" do you mean that you mean that you want it to be a comma separated string?

Comment: Yes exactly sorry new to php programming

Comment: You have two options, you can keep the code i gave and use implode... http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

or you can just concatenate the string as you go instead of loading it into an array.

Comment: Like this? This just outputs ARRAY

foreach($order->getItemsCollection() as $item)
{
$orderItems['sku'][] = $item->getProduct()->getSku();
}

$comma_separated = implode(",", $orderItems);
echo $comma_separated;

Comment: See my edited answer

Comment: thanks for the help that was what i was looking for, I over complicated it.